# Neo4j - How to design graph database based on type and / or level of relation

Tags: neo4j

For example in the work environment, family, community, etc. Example:

On the A side, B is the Boss - On the B side, A is the Subordinate.
On the C side, D is the Teacher - On the D side, C is the student.
On the E side, F is Father - On the F side, E is a child.
On the E side, D is the Teacher - On the D side, E is the student.

Attributes such as superiors, subordinates, teachers, students, fathers, children, and so on can at any time increase, change and delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3 relationship types to represent your "relations". For example, `REPORTS_TO`, `HAS_STUDENT`, `HAS_CHILD`:

```
(a)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(b)
(d)-[:HAS_STUDENT]->(c)
(f)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(e)
(d)-[:HAS_STUDENT]->(e)
```

While it is true that a neo4j relationship (e.g., of type `HAS_STUDENT`) must be created with a specific direction (e.g., from a teacher node to a student node), it can be just as easily (and efficiently) traversed in the opposite (or either) direction when you make a query.

Comment: I 've got it. But what about this. The relation should enough with one type of edge, say (c)-[:RELATES_TO {as:"student",to:"teacher"}]->(d). If so, how to replace the values of "as" and "to" properties with argument referenced to a node with data set properties (param:"string/words"), a node though without a relationship.

Comment: Traversal of the DB would be very inefficient if you had just a single relationship type. Neo4j would have to iterate through all the relationships of every candidate node to find the ones with the wanted `as` and `to` values. You definitely want to avoid that. Perhaps you should explain in your question what your use cases are, as that is not obvious.

Comment: It seems that I am still affected by relational thinking. Sorry. Thanks. Your suggestion is very enlightening. I will try to justify my way of thinking first.

Comment: Great. By the way, since you have enough reputation points, you have gained the ability to [Vote Up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) answers you find helpful.